# How to generate a list of random numbers between a certain range, then get numbers not included in that list

Tags: java, random, int

I have generated a list of 20 unique random numbers between 1 and 300, and used that for what I need to use it for. However, I also need the numbers that have not made it to the list to be added into another list for use in another function.

Here is the code I have used to generate the random list of 20 numbers:

```
JToggleButton[][] p = new JToggleButton[5][4];
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < p[i].length; j++) {

            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((300 - 1) + 1) + 1;

            while (list.contains(randomNum)) {
                randomNum = rand.nextInt((300 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            }

            list.add(randomNum);

// rest of code that I need the random number list for
```

I need to get the other 280 numbers not included in this 20 item list into another list, but I am unsure how to actually get these 'unused' numbers

Comment: rand.nextInt((300 - 1) + 1) + 1 is strange a little bit

Comment: @user8426627 could you tell me why?

Comment: @user8426627 it actually refers to `rand.nextInt((upperLimit - lowerLimit) + 1) + lowerLimit` which makes sense, it just looks weird with everything being `1` and not having variables.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 300).filter(item -> !list.contains(item)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `List` with all 300 numbers to begin with, and then when you add a random number to the other list, just remove the same number from the `List` with all of the values:

Create the list:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> excludedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(300);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i++){
        excludedNumbers.add(i);
    }
```

Add a single line to your current code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p[i].length; i++) {

            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((300 - 1) + 1) + 1;

            while (randomList.contains(randomNum)) {
                randomNum = rand.nextInt((300 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            }

            excludedNumbers.remove((Integer) randomNum); // the new line
            randomList.add(randomNum);
    }
}
```

The cast of `Integer` ensures the `List` uses the `Object` remove function rather than the `int` remove option.

Comment: this is what I am looking for, but then how could I get the individual int items out of the list to then add each of them to a database table for example?

Comment: @hiro228 Just iterate over the list like you would any other list?  You would most likely need to use JDBC to connect to the database.  This is out of the scope of this question though and I recommend you try something out and make a new question about the database part if you come across an issue attempting it.

Comment: I already have the database set up, what i meant was that i need to put those individual int items into the database individually. Even just to print them out individually on console instead of [1, 4, 77, 299, 3...]. I am a complete beginner to java

Comment: @hiro228 Also, I corrected the bounds on the first array to be 1 to 300 instead of 0 to 299, minor mistake on the loop from earlier.  Thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need two lists exactly as you say, then here's a method of doing that:

```
final int numberOfInts = 300;
List<Integer> excluded = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfInts ; i++) {
    excluded.add(i);
}

Random rand = new Random();
List<Integer> included = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    included.add(excluded.remove(rand.nextInt(excluded.size())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me forever to understand what your question was asking.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> otherNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
        if(!list.contains(x+1)) {
            otherNumbers.add(x+1);
        }
    }
```

You can just populate a new list by skipping over the values the 20 number list contains.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to generate a separate list and populate it with every number between 1 and 300.  After that, just iterate through your list of generated random numbers and remove those elements from your 1 through 300 list.  Something like this..

```
ArrayList<Integer> list300 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
For (int i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    list300.add(i);
}

For (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list300.contains(list[i])) {
        list300.remove(Integer.vaueOf(list[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right as it was kind of hard to understand for me.
I would do it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> notIncludedNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++){
   if (!list.contains(i))
      notIncludedNumbers.add(i);
}
```

You iterate over all the numbers from 1 to 300 and add them to the `notIncludedNumbers` list if they are not contained in your list with the 20 random numbers.
I hope I could help.